# Deploy a trained tensorflow model in a file format into a Raspberry Pi

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, raspberry-pi3, restore

I recently built a tensorflow model and trained it; Here is the input.

```
data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,20,1]) #Number of examples, number of input, dimension of each input
```

After a while of computation through LSTM cells, and dense layers, the final prediction is made here:

```
logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=den3, units=1)
```

After training it and saving it, like so:

```
for i in range(epoch):
    for j in range(batchSize):
        loss = sess.run([step,error],feed_dict={data:np.array([tx[j]]),target:np.array([ty[j]])})
        saver.save(sess,'model')
```

This in turn saves 4 files which are 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJVAV.png)

I then copy then over to the Pi, but i don't know how to just open them and pass some inputs and read the output, without building the whole graph and assigning each variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to copy the files over to your Pi and then run `saver.restore()` to load them again. Here's an example of doing that:

```
from tensorflow.python.training import saver as saver_lib
saver = saver_lib.Saver()
saver.restore(sess, 'model')
```

This is based on https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py